# Could "The flesh of the god" be an ambiguous title? Why?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-order, phrase-meaning

Is the phrase "Flesh of the god" grammatically and semantically acceptable, or should it be "Flesh of the gods"?

I am writing an article and I'd like to use it for the title. I am from Finland, so I really don't know if this is the correct way to say this.

I'm speaking about any god. In my article, I'm describing a man as if he were a god. He's a normal human being, but he's placed himself upon a pedestal so as to be worshipped as a god. The story then goes on to say that someone kills this man and cuts off a piece of his flesh.

If I used the definite article, "the" before *god*, would it imply a specific god? Should I use an uppercase letter for "God"? What do you think "Flesh of the god" means? I mean, how would this story go, if the title were "Flesh of the god"?

Comment: How can we possibly know what you mean by the phrase you don't know how to say unless you supply a context and explain what you expect to convey by those words?

Comment: Are you talking about more than one god? Only one? Any god, or one in particular? Or even God with a capital G?

Comment: @Mirja, are you looking for a word to describe a human who has powers like those of a god? Or do you mean meat (for eating) made from dead gods? Or maybe you mean something to do with [transubstantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transubstantiation)? I'm afraid it's still completely unclear what you're trying to say.

Comment: Still not very clear, but it may be you mean 'god in human form' or something similar. If so no, this is quite wrong. *Flesh of the gods* would be a tangible substance; Christians might consider the phrase *flesh of god* a blasphemous reference to the consecrated Host.

Comment: @A E I don't mean god in Christian sense at all. A E is right, my meaning is closer to the edible chunk of god's flesh. @TimLymington

Comment: @MirjaLahtinen So it's the flesh of one god, but isn't not a *specific* god?  In the same way we might talk about the flesh of a chicken without caring about the identity of the specific chicken?

Comment: @smithkm You are correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA this man is normal human, but he is placing himself upon pedestals to be god for others. Story tells that someone kills this man and then cuts off piece of his flesh.

Comment: Then **"The Flesh of a god"** could fit as a title. The word *god* is in lowercase which tells the reader the story is not about the monotheistic Christian god, whose name is spelt God, and there's the indefinite article "a" which suggests it could be one of many gods.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If I would use "the" before god, it would be specific god? And then one should use Uppercase letters for "God"?

Comment: The term God is a proper noun, a name given by Jews and Christians to their deity. Likewise, Allah must be spelt with a capital letter. If you want to reopen the question, you should edit your question and include your last comment, it is a relevant and, above all, an on topic question!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I understand. What you think "Flesh of the god" means? How would it be fitting title? I mean, how would this story go if the title were "Flesh of the god" Or can it be used at all?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It could be, since I have not started this article yet, so I have not fully decided will it be a specific god, but it could be so I want to know my options for the title, if I would use one specific god. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MirjaLahtinen, then "the flesh of the god" is an excellent title. It is somewhat ambiguous, but it sounds like the story itself resolves that ambiguity. So it's ambiguous in an interesting way.

Comment: c.f. [Cronos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronus) devouring Poseidon: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Rubens_saturn.jpg In that image, Cronos is definitely eating Poseidon's 'flesh'.

Comment: @AE Do I need use "the" before the word "flesh"? Can it be just "Flesh of the god"?

Comment: @MirjaLahtinen, either way is ok. It's (IMO) a better title without the leading "the", because it's briefer and slightly more ambiguous  whether you're using 'flesh' figuratively or literally (which makes it more interesting IMO). But that's a matter of personal style/preference really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds from the comments as though you mean literally meat (for eating) made from a dead god (or someone posing as a god).

If that's the case then "the flesh of the god" does make sense as a title. It is somewhat ambiguous, but it sounds as though the story itself resolves that ambiguity. So it's ambiguous in an interesting way.

It's (IMO) a better title without the leading "the", because it's briefer and slightly more ambiguous whether you're using 'flesh' figuratively or literally (which makes it more interesting IMO). But that's a matter of personal style/preference really.

The ambiguity will be between:

> The soft substance consisting of muscle and fat that is found between the skin and bones of a human or an animal

versus

> The human body and its physical needs and desires, especially as contrasted with the mind or the soul

[ODO: flesh](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flesh)

versus

> II. Extended and figurative uses (chiefly of Biblical origin).
>
> 7. one's (own) flesh : one's near kindred or descendants. Now rare exc. in flesh and blood n.

with a hint of

> 9 c. The body (of Christ) regarded as spiritually ‘eaten’ by believers; also applied mystically to the bread in the sacrament of the Lord's Supper.

[OED: flesh](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/71460)

So a reader encountering it for the first time could be unsure whether you mean "kindred of the gods" or "meat made from a god" or "remarkably good meat", and there's also the slightly unsettling implication of a reference of transubstantiation. Which on the whole makes it a good title in my opinion, because (if I understand correctly) you intend *both* of those first two meanings.

Answer (score 0):

"The flesh of the god" refers to the flesh of a specific god as you are using the definite article "the".  "the god" means that there's a particular god the identity of which should be known to the reader/listener within this context.

To refer to the flesh of a non-specific god, you would use the indefinite article "a": "the flesh of a god".  In this case, nothing is being said about the identity of the god.

You might also treat "god" as a modifier of "flesh" or create a compound to get "god flesh", "godflesh" respectively.